# Мерцание маркеров в Q3DScatter в PySide2

Tags: python, qt, pyside2

При попытке визуализировать движение молекул средствами PySide2 с использование Q3DScatter, столкнулся с артефактом в виде мерцающих маркеров ([видео](https://youtu.be/p1aOnUNH1tk)).
Перестроение маркеров осущестляю слеудющим образом:

```
    def drawData(self):
        data = []
        for mol in self._s_data.getCurrentCoordinates():
            data.append(QVector3D(*mol[:3]))
        self.series.dataProxy().removeItems(0,len(data))
        self.series.dataProxy().addItems(data)
```

Подозреваю, что проблема в этом участке кода.
Как можно избавиться от этого дефекта?
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Где-то надо включить двойную буферизацию